# How to autodeploy Django in EC2 and React in S3

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an app created in Django and React, but there are few problems that I am facing :-

As I will have a large database(postgres) exclusily for a single user, I am creating different AWS EC2 instance for every user.

Whenever there is a new user then I have to go and manually install postgres, setup nginx and other important things and this is just for Django in EC2. Then I setup ReactJS frontend in Amazon S3.

How can i automate this so that when a paid user signs up, everything happens automatically.

The following should happen automatically:
- Automatically create a new EC2 instance, and deploy backend (This including installing several libraries, Postgres, Redis, async task queue (We use Huey which is like Celery), making migrations and other trivial stuff) 
- Automatically make an S3 bucket and deploy frontend for the user. We will have to setup domains .etc for this.

Would like to know your inputs on how to approach this problem.

Comment: IAM users? You can put them for AWS Service Catalog, so they can provision products (based on your specific permissions and requirements).

Comment: Consider AWS CloudFormation https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/ for that automatically creating AWS resources such as EC2 instances and S3 buckets. UserData section of EC2 would let you script all the software installation within the instance (libraries. Huey etc).